# How to pass md5-encrypted password to IMAP server instead of plain text

Tags: java, email, passwords, imap

I am writing an email client which is part of a larger web application for a company. The user is authenticated by logging into the whole web application by creating an MD5 hash and comparing it to the one that is stored in the database.

However, this is outside of my scope. I have only access to the one way hash in the database. As the same credentials for email and web app shall be used, is there a way to pass the MD5 hash instead of plain text to an IMAP server through Java Mail? I would think so, as the mail server would do nothing else but creating a hash of the plain text password and comparing it anyway. But how to do it in IMAP in Java Mail?

Thanks

Comment: The point of storing hashes instead of passwords is that the passwords cannot be easily stolen. If some service would accept a hash instead of the password for authentication this would no longer hold. The hashes could be seen as password equivalent that are now stored in clear.

Comment: Well, I do use SSL for the IMAP transfer. That should handle the security concern. However, the point is that there is no way to decypher the password in order to pass it to the mail server.

Comment: This helps for network sniffing but not if the attacker has access to the DB.